# How to retrieve local.settings.json for an Azure FunctionApp

Tags: azure-functions, azure-powershell

I can retrieve the ApplicationSettings easily for an Azure FunctionApp with **Get-AzFunctionAppSetting** but I can't seem to find a way to get the associated local.settings.json file. Can anybody steer me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Best I have at the minute is to use the Kudu API to retrieve the file. First you need to get authentication credentials and then add them to your iwr request to GET the file. Detailed explanation here https://blog.kloud.com.au/2016/08/30/interacting-with-azure-web-apps-virtual-file-system-using-powershell-and-the-kudu-api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local.setting.json file contains app settings that Core Tools uses while running ***locally***. You can publish the accompanying local.settings.json file using the [--publish-local-settings option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-core-tools-reference?tabs=v2#func-azure-functionapp-publish).

When you publish make sure these settings are added to the function app in Azure. from there you can try reading app settings using

```
Get-AzFunctionAppSetting -Name MyAppName -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName
```

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Work with Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cwindows%2Ccsharp%2Cportal%2Cbash#local-settings)
2. [Azure Functions Core Tools reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-core-tools-reference?tabs=v2#func-azure-functionapp-publish)